# UIScrollview Pull to refresh not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh, visual-format-language

```
  self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [self.objDiscussiontopic addSubview:self.refreshControl];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)refreshTable {
    //TODO: refresh your data
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

This is the code i am using to add refresh controller in my scroll view.
But when i pull down the scroll view the refresh control is not showing and the targeted method is also not called why ?

I am searching this for a while but didn't get any proper answer .

One more thing scrollview having VFL Constraint some thing like this :

```
//Pin scrolview to Parent View
    [VFLConstraint allignSubViewViewHorizentallyWithSubView:self.objDiscussiontopic OverSuperView:[self view]];
    [VFLConstraint allignSubViewViewVerticallyWithSubView:self.objDiscussiontopic OverSuperView:[self view] WithTopPading:[CommonFunction convertIphone6ToIphone5:0] AndBotomPading:[CommonFunction convertIphone6ToIphone5:57]];


+ (void)allignSubViewViewHorizentallyWithSubView:(UIView *)subView OverSuperView:(UIView *)superView{

    NSDictionary *viewDict= NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView);
    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewDict]];
}

+ (void)allignSubViewViewVerticallyWithSubView:(UIView *)subView OverSuperView:(UIView *)superView WithTopPading:(float)topPading AndBotomPading:(float)bottomPading{

    NSDictionary *viewDict= NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView);
    NSDictionary *metrics=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:topPading],@"topPading",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:bottomPading],@"bottomPading", nil];
    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topPading-[subView]-bottomPading-|" options:0 metrics: metrics views:viewDict]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to:
`[self.scrollView insertSubview:self.refreshControl atIndex:0];`

Check the contentSize it can be less that frame size, if so use this line of code:
`self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `UIRefreshControl` is designed to work with plain scroll views. Apple's docs specifically refer to [UITableViews when talking about refresh control.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/)

You can look at third party pull to refresh libraries to add this to UIScrollView